Intermediate connection point between wires and volume pot
I have a guitar with a vintage EMG 81 i.e. not the solder-less version. Sometimes, quite rarely I'd say, a weird sounds starts to appear while I am playing. The appearance of these sounds is random, it does not happen when I touch a metal part or something. The sound resembles a strong wind, a storm or something like that. I think it is either a grounding problem or the fact that the electronics cavity is not shielded at all, perhaps a combination of both.
Anyway, the first thing that I notice is that the soldering on the back of the volume pot (the guitar is one humbucker one volume only) is very poor. So the first thing I want to do is to re-solder pretty much all the connections.
In the picture below we see that some wires do not go directly into the volume pot. They are first connected to the side of the electronic cavity, then are connected to the volume pot. See for example the thick white wire (I think it comes from the pickup) and two thin black wires

My main question is do you know why there is this intermediary connection? Why these wires, that are first connected to the side of the electronic cavity, are not directly connected to the volume pot, to the lug or to the back of the pot?
Also, I haven't fully investigated what each of the wires are (there is only one whole from which they come out), but I guess this wiring is somewhat different from the wiring diagram below from EMG. If that's indeed the case, am I safe to follow the wiring diagram below?


What amp are you using? The sort of rushing wind sound you describe is more likely the amp rather than anything in the guitar, the guitar can't really make that sort of sound. The intermediary connection looks like what you would see if the cavity was shielded, it is there to make sure everything, the pot backs, the shielding etc is drawn to ground potential. This is how shielding works, make sure any outside source of signal meets the ground of the instrument first. It looks as though maybe your guitar cavity has been shielded, then painted, but I can't be sure.

it is certainly the guitar, not the amp, as none of the other guitars that I have have this sound, with the same amp, obviously

Can you look more carefully at the pot?  I would have expected only three connections, all at tabs:  input, output, and "commmon" aka "return."  I'm wondering if some genius soldered a connection to the pot case in an attempt to tie that to the return level as well.  If so , that should be removed.
The return to the battery, I would have thought, should be tied to the system ground, in which case the Bare from EMG ought to have gone to the third tab on the pot, not the case.   But I don't know what your amplifier does with two separate 'ground' inputs.  Again, my guess would be that the 'sleeve' and 'tip' are intended to be floating with respect to the "battery", except that this would negate any applied voltage.
But again, all that mess at the pot is a bit mysterious, and should be "buzzed out" independent of the pickup and battery leads.

not sure I follow which comments refer to the wiring of my guitar and which refer to the wiring diagram. Do you see anything wrong with the wiring diagram?

@BCArg  From the photo, I get the feeling that way too many things got soldered together.  That's why I suggested buzzing things out rather than trying to make a diagram based only on visual exam

what exactly you mean by 'buzzing things out'? How about just undoing the current wiring (which do look a bit all over the place indeed) and re-wiring according to the diagram that I posted, beneath the photo (of the current diagram)

@BCArg  "Buzz out" means to test each little piece of the circuit with an ohmmeter (or voltmeter if the battery is switched on) to verify the resistance or lack thereof.  Then take every item you want to be at earth ground and solder directly to the outer shield of the connector. This prevents ground loops.
